# How to put php code in the style attribute of a div element?

Tags: php, html

I did this but it doesn't work. I need to put user input of width and height into php and draw shape.

```php
echo "<div style='width:<?php $sirina?>;height: <?php $visina?>;border:1px solid black;'";
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to rewrite `<?php ?>`, just like this:

```
echo "<div style='width:". $sirina." px;height:'". $visina." px;border:1px solid black;'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write php code between html tag, html attribute, html tag name so php code should be written in style attribute. like this:

```php
<span><</span>div style="height: <span><</span>?php echo $h;?>px; width: <span><</span>?php echo $w;?>px; "><span><</span>/div>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your sample code to make it valid?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this syntax:

```
<?= ?>
```

you can put any variable between this tags and it will echo that variable automatically.

so your code will refactor to this:

```
echo "<div style='width:<?= $sirina ?>;height: <?= $visina ?>;border:1px solid black;'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're not echoing your `$sirina` and `$visina` variables properly.
So your code should look something like this:

```
echo "<div style='width: $sirina px; height: $visina px; border: 1px solid black;'";
```